# Helping for 7bits CRC in 40Bits message(message need to be initial with seed value)

Tags: c, algorithm, crc

Hi I'm implementing the CRC calculation function fro my project.
The parameter is below

```
Polynomial : x7 + x5 + x4 + x2 + x +1  --> 0xB7(0b10110111)
Seed Value : 0b1110000                 --> 0x70
Message Example                        --> 0x 84 80 00 00 00(message[5]={0x00(pending zero for CRC bit),0x00,0x00,0x08,0x84})
```

So far what I know is I need to initial the message with seed value by `" message[4] (0x84) XOR seedvalue "`,
then the message become `message[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x64}`,and I've searched some information about CRC Algorithm and sample code in C.
Therefore I write the CRC calculation function with the parameter above,here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
uint8_t crc=0 ;
uint8_t POLYNOMIAL =0xB7 ;

uint8_t crcCount(uint8_t message[],uint8_t byte)
{
    for(int i =0; i <byte ; i++)
    {
        crc ^=message[i] ;
        for( int bit =0 ; bit< 8; bit++)
        {
            if((crc & 0x40U))
            {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL ;
            }
            else
            {
                crc <<=1u ;
            }
        }

    }
    return crc ;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t c_value ;
    uint8_t message[5]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x64};
    c_value = crcCount(message,5);
    printf("CRC = 0x%x",c_value);
    return 0;
}
```

And I got the wrong answer `CRC = 0x33`,because the answer is `0x7D`.
Does anybody can teach me which part is wrong ?? Thanks A LOT!!
I've stuck in this issue for a while.

Comment: I can't make sense of your `Message Example` - how do you get from `84 80 00 00 00` to `0x00` `,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x84`. And what's the notation `message[4] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x64}` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!! I post wrong code that one above is my very first one version!!!
the message shoule be  `0x8408000000, message[5]={0x84,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00}`,
after initial is `message[5]={0x64,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00}; 0x84 ^ (0x70 <<1) = 0x64`  the last version code is below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
uint8_t crc=0 ;
uint8_t POLYNOMIAL =0xB7 ;

uint8_t crcCount(uint8_t message[],uint8_t byte)
{
    for(int i=0; i < byte ; i ++)
    {
        crc ^=message[i] ;
        for( int bit =0 ; bit< 8; bit++)
        {
            if((crc & 0x80))
            {
                crc = (crc <<1) ^ (POLYNOMIAL<<1) ;
            }
            else
            {
                crc <<=1u ;
            }
        }
  
    }
    return crc >>1  ;
}


int main()
{
    uint8_t c_value ;
    uint8_t message[5]={0x64,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    c_value = crcCount(message,5);
    printf("CRC = 0x%x",c_value);
    return 0;
}
```

and the answer is `0x7D`,but it should be `0x56`,it's still wrong

Sorry for the stupid mistake..........

Comment: Don't add an answer. Simply edit the question to correct it.